# strange dock appears on desktop

Tags: dock

This dock (I mean its looks like a dock but unclickable) and after I installed some plugins and extensions for nautilus from terminal and restart pc this show up!

Extensions that I installed before:

```
sudo apt-get install wbar udiskie tortoisehg-nautilus subliminal-nautilus seahorse-nautilus rabbitvcs-nautilus rabbitvcs-core ooo-thumbnailer nautilus-wipe nautilus-scripts-manager nautilus-script-manager nautilus-script-debug nautilus-script-collection-svn nautilus-script-audio-convert nautilus-nextcloud nautilus-kdeconnect nautilus-image-converter nautilus-ideviceinfo nautilus-hide nautilus-gtkhash nautilus-font-manager nautilus-filename-repairer nautilus-extension-burner nautilus-admin mat2 makexvpics libnautilus-extension-dev libfm4 intltool heif-thumbnailer gnome-hwp-support fvwm-crystal folder-color eiciel easytag-nautilus clamtk-gnome clamtk caja-seahorse cairo-dock-shortcuts-plug-in -y
```

[strange dock appears on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWYG9.png)

Comment: Did you try removing "some plugins and extensions for nautilus"?

Comment: I installed too many extensions and I don't know which one cause this! `sudo apt search nautilus` every thing after this command.

Comment: If you don't say what you did (in detail), how is anyone supposed to help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include that information.

Comment: you installed [some `cairo` stuff](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/cairo-dock-shortcuts-plug-in), and `cairo` is a dock .... try that

Comment: So finally I found it, it was this: 
`wbar/impish,now 2.3.4-10 amd64 [residual-config]
  light and fast launch bar`
And the dock is disappeared.